# How to parse multiple <ul><li> html with Python?

Tags: python, parsing

I have a document like this:

```
 TEXT
 TEXT
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li>4</li>
 </ul>
 ANOTHER TEXT
```

What can I use to transform it into:

```
TEXT
TEXT
* 1
** 2
** 3
* 4
ANOTHER TEXT
```

I need to parse the ul/li parts only, TEXT (it doesn't have ul/li) should be left intact without any changes.

I wrote a parser

```
def uls(str):
    str = re.sub(r'<li>(.*?)</li>', r"<li><!!\1></li>", str, flags=re.M | re.U | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    ret_text = []

    ul_level = 0
    text = ''

    pattern = re.compile(r'(<.*?>)')
    for tag in re.findall(pattern, str):
        if tag == '<ul>':
            ul_level += 1
        if tag == '</ul>':
            ul_level -= 1
            if ul_level == 0:
                ret_text.append(text)
                text = ''
        if re.search(r'<!!(.*?)>', tag, re.M | re.U | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL):
            text = text + ('*' * ul_level) + re.sub(r'<!!(.*?)>', r' \1\n', tag, re.M | re.U | re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)

    return ret_text
```

It's produces correct array, but how can I replace

- ...

with this code?

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, [don't parse html with regex!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags); use a proper parser.
Second, even with a proper parser it's going to be difficult to get you to your expected output. The following (admittedly, somewhat hackish) should be you close enough...

```
import lxml.html as lh #you'll have to read up on lxml/xpath...

ht = """<html>TEXT1
 TEXT2
 <ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <ul>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
  </ul>
  <li>4</li>
 </ul>
 ANOTHER TEXT3
 </html>"""

doc = etree.fromstring(ht)
tree = etree.ElementTree(doc)

txts = ['text','tail']
for elem in doc.xpath('//*'):
    for txt in txts:
        try:
            target= eval(f'elem.{txt}').strip()
            if target:
                #the next line counts the number of tiers and prints the appropriate number of '*'s:
                print(tree.getelementpath(elem).count('/') * "*", target)
        except:
            continue
```

Output:

```
 TEXT1
 TEXT2
 ANOTHER TEXT3
* 1
** 2
** 3
* 4
```

As I said, pretty close.